# Configuring cost threshold for parallelism & Max Degree of Parallelism

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

In production environment found that the default value of 5 is there for Cost Threshold for parallelism and 0 for Max Degree of Parallelism. From various resources I understand that it is not the optimal value and has to be changed. Now the question I am trying to figure out is what might be the optimal value for my environment.

With the help of sys.dm_os_sys_info found that the environment has:

- Physical CPU = 1 & Logical CPUs = 4

So does it mean I can set Max Degree of Parallelism as 4? If not please help me understand what to look for and decide the value for it.

Made use of Jonathan Kehayias below script:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; 

WITH XMLNAMESPACES   
   (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan')  
SELECT  
        query_plan AS CompleteQueryPlan, 
        n.value('(@StatementText)[1]', 'VARCHAR(4000)') AS StatementText, 
        n.value('(@StatementOptmLevel)[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)') AS StatementOptimizationLevel, 
        n.value('(@StatementSubTreeCost)[1]', 'VARCHAR(128)') AS StatementSubTreeCost, 
        n.query('.') AS ParallelSubTreeXML,  
        ecp.usecounts, 
        ecp.size_in_bytes 
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS ecp 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS eqp 
CROSS APPLY query_plan.nodes('/ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/StmtSimple') AS qn(n) 
WHERE  n.query('.').exist('//RelOp[@PhysicalOp="Parallelism"]') = 1
```

and this is the summary I found:

- StatementSubTree cost: Mean is 36.5, Mode is 12.78 and Median is 9.38
- Totally ~850 entries out of which ~750 entries subtree cost is less than 50. And ~25 is above 100 & out of which 15 is above 500.

So wondering should I change the cost threshold value as nearest to median or mean. If that is not the way to do please guide me the steps to be followed.

Wait Stats result:
[image][image][image]

Comment: Before making any changes -- are you actually facing a performance problem around parallel queries or CPU usage? Have you looked at wait stats?

Comment: I checked the wait stats and top most is CXPacket and within the top 10 or 12 items I remember seeing these wait stats as well. Latch_XX, PageIoLatch_xx, SOS_scheduler_yeild. Got complaints from end users that pages are loading slow. Not very sure how to narrow down and say its a performance issues due to parallel queries.

Comment: That's not much to go on. Head over to firstresponderkit.org and grab `sp_BlitzFirst`, then run  `EXEC sp_BlitzFirst @SinceStartup = 1` and **update your question** with the wait stats results. Full disclosure, I co-author many scripts in that repo.

Comment: If you are seeing parallel queries for an OLTP workload, that suggests query and index tuning is needed. Increasing the cost threshold and/or reducing MAXDOP might mitigate the problem with end user response time won't address the root cause.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Sure would try it in office tomorrow and share the details. Thanks

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Ran sp_BlitzFirst as you had mentioned and have updated the question with its result. Please review.

Comment: So far the only symptom mentioned is slow page loads. You should take steps to exclude the possibility that it's your web server. It might have have nothing to do with parallelism. It could be parameter sniffing or lack of indexes. Don't make any changes until you have some baseline and some understanding of what the root cause is.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for your suggestion. Though I am not sure but I assume it should be possible to identify the root cause with the help of Wait stats. Hoping that might be the reason for Erik to ask for those details.

Comment: Wait stats will help assist with performance issues if they are in the database. They won't assist if they are in the web app. _Often_ performance issues can be isolated to the database but the first rule of troubleshooting is not to jump to incorrect conclusions i.e.: your symptom is in the web app. This doesn't mean it's the database. I suggest you isolate your symptom to a particular query. Then you're dealing with something more substantial than 'pages are loading slow'. In extreme cases it might just be that your web server has run out of resources, or you have a badly written web page.

Comment: Looking at the wait stats, SQL Server is bored. In 1700 hours of uptime you don't have a single prominent wait. I wouldn't change any settings, and I'd follow @Nick.McDermaid 's advice to look elsewhere.

Comment: What does bored mean here? So as Nick & Dan suggested I should look into the SP/statements which are eating up the SQL resources right? Is there specific params I should fire with sp_blitz to narrow down on those details?